# How to implement banner rotator

Tags: session, ruby-on-rails-4, cookies

I created RoR4 project and I want to implement banner rotation system with managment including capping, total views and expiration date. The main problem for me is to store number of views of specific banner per uniq user. So imagine this scene :

we have 3 banners and just one place(for simplicity) where I show them

user comes to website

- Banner A showed first time

user clicks link

- Banner B showed first time

user clicks link

- Banner C showed first time

user click link

- Banner A should be shown the second time

How can I know that user see banner the second time ?

Searching through the internet i found that if anybody wants to create banner rotator then mostly they use cookies...

Should I prepare cookie with values for example

```
[{banner_id:1, views:1}, {banner_id:2, view:3}]
```

and with every http request check cookie and modify its values ?

We all know that cookies can be easly removed. Is it some better way to do it ?

Please dont instruct me about reinventing the wheel. I know that OpenX and similar things exist.

Any help would be appreciate !

Comment: There is no way to absolutely identify unique web users which they cannot defeat by wiping something out on their browser.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, generally you would do this using cookies (or in Rails, using sessions which are based on cookies). Yes, cookies are easy to remove, but usually for something like banners the small number of users who will do this is usually not a problem. If it's a problem then you probably want to implement actual authentication and force users to login, and then you can store the banner viewing information in your DB.